# Where are the graves of the mothers?

Tags: avot-patriarch-fathers, imahot-matriarch-mothers

In Breishit 23:2, Rash"i cites Breishit Rabba which mentions that 4 couples were buried there. (I asked a separate question about Adam and Chava).

When visiting Me'arat Hamachpela, one finds signs for each of the father's graves. Were their wives buried right next to them, but it's just a question of the signs that mentioned just the fathers? Or were they buried elsewhere?

Comment: The modern signs are bogus. They're just evenly distributed around the modern room.

Comment: Well the Chachmos Hatorah says Rachel is buried there,and the Yalkut Ruveini says that Moshe and Tziporah was buried there

Comment: @sam aren't there explicit pesukim in the Torah that contradict both of those?

Comment: Nope,the Chachmos HaTorah explains that Rachel was buried at kever Rachel for one night and then transferred to MH,he says it from the wording of the passuk מצבת קבורתו רחל,its a matzeivah for her burial spot till this day but not where she actually is. With regards to Moshe and Tziporah he also was transferred from the spot he was initially collected into.

Comment: @sam ולא ידע איש את קבורתו עד היום הזה

Comment: An Ish yes  ,but not a Malach that's the pshat I saw